# Parallelization of neighborhood point deletion

Tags: c++, c, cuda, parallel-processing, computer-vision

I am implementing the Good Features To Track/Shi-Tomasi corner detection algorithm on CUDA and need to find a way to parallelize the following part of the algorithm:

1. I start with an array of points obtained from an image sorted according to a certain intensity value (an eigenvalue of a previous calculation).
2. Starting with the first point of the array, I remove any point in the array that is within a certain physical distance of the first point. (This distance is calculated on the image plane, not on the array).
3. On the resulting array, we repeat step two for the remaining points.

Is this somehow parallelizable, specifically on CUDA? I'm suspecting not, since there will obviously be dependencies across the image.

Comment: As far as i know this algorithm is called non-maximum supression. Try searching it.

Comment: I think it is related to non maxima suppression, but is slightly different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the article [Accelerated Corner-Detector Algorithms](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.165.3366%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&rct=j&q=non-maximum%20suppression%20gpu%20-canny%20-directional%20harris&ei=LbimTdDMJ8j4sgaW2fybCA&usg=AFQjCNFp0gsaVrhDW4Zh2dDWQtMa64uAaw&sig2=WcDYxql0K6KzU0oETUez3Q&cad=rja) describes the way to solve this problem.